# Bootsrap column width wider then image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a column with a 230x320 placeholder `class='img-responsive'` image inside it. the image is 230x320, but the column width is `col-md-3`.

The issue is that the image width is smaller then the column width, so space is left over to the right. Also, when the column is changed to `col-md-2`, the image turns responsive, thus displays the image smaller than the 230x320 size.

Is there a way to keep this column responsive, but decrease the width of the column, but keep the default bootstrap padding on the right?

Here is the image like so: [image]

I have added the snippet code, but bootstrap is not working, maybe I have my links where they are not suppose to be?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class-="col-md-12">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="profilephoto" class="col-sm-2 control-label custom-label">Profile Photo</label>
      <div class="col-md-3 profile-img"><img src="http://placehold.it/230x320" alt="profile-img" class="img-rounded img-responsive"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/130x130" alt="avatar" class="img-circle">
    <div class="caption">Avatar</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md outline btn-block upload-btn">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Upload photo
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's behavior is appropriate based on your markup. From the Bootstrap documentation on the `img-responsive` class [[link]](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images):

> This applies `max-width: 100%;`, `height: auto;` and `display: block;`
>   to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

The behavior you need is not `max-width: 100%;` but rather `width: 100%;`, which will scale the image to the full width of the parent element.

This [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexgivens/pen/pyVERO) demonstrates the override, however in the final product I recommend adding a custom CSS class to the `img` tag.

Comment: ahh! Thanks, Alex :)

Comment: ohh, actually it has made the image larger then its 230x320 size...how do I keep that specific size though?

Comment: For your image to fill the width of a responsive column at larger screen sizes, only one requirement may be met. Either the image must expand beyond its 230px width to fill the column (my answer above), or the column must be restricted to a maximum width of 230px (effectively breaking Bootstrap's grid system).

Comment: I understand now, thanks for clarifying that up for me.